# Why is result of pattern along path no circle?

Tags: inkscape

I've tried this video tutorial and want to put a pattern along a path of a circle. The problem is now that the result is like a rectangle and not a circle. Can anybody tell me why?

Thanks!

[image: Path before and after applying the pattern]

Comment: Can you add a link to "this video tutorial"?